# Use pure Kotlin function as Junit5 methodsource

Tags: kotlin, junit5, parametrized-testing

I am curious if in the Kotlin, in the parameterized tests in Junit5, i can use the method outside the class as the @MethodSource.

I know about 2 ways to use @MethodSource in Kotlin - companion object and @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS). I wonder if it can be done in a different way, for example by declaring a method outside the class and using some annotation? I tried to do it this way, but it does not work, I wonder if something similar can be done.

```java
class GenerationStatusTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("provideStatusesToTest")
    internal fun shouldStatusesHaveExpectedAbilities(generationStatus: GenerationStatus, assertions:(GenerationStatus)->Unit) {
        assertions(generationStatus)
    }
}

fun provideStatusesToTest(): Stream<Arguments> {
    return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(WAITING, canDoNothing),
            Arguments.of(PROCESSING, canDoNothing)
    )
}
```

```
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: Could not find factory method [provideStatusesToTest] in class [com.test.enums.GenerationStatusTest]
    at org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodArgumentsProvider.lambda$getMethod$4(MethodArgumentsProvider.java:83)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[JUnit documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-MethodSource) says

> An external, static factory method can be referenced by providing its fully qualified method name as demonstrated in the following example.

And [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-level-functions) says

> All the functions and properties declared in a file app.kt inside a package org.example, including extension functions, are compiled into static methods of a Java class named org.example.AppKt.

So if the package name is `com.test.enums` (from the error message), and your file name is `GenerationStatusTest.kt`, then the generated class containing `provideStatusesToTest` is `com.test.GenerationStatusTestKt`, so the annotation you need is

```
@MethodSource("com.test.enums.GenerationStatusTestKt#provideStatusesToTest")
```

Comment: I knew that you could reference function from another class that way, but didn't think it works the same with functions outside of a class.

Answer (score 42):

The best solution is adding `@JvmStatic` annotation to your provider function.

```
class SumTest {

    @ParameterizedTest(name = "{0} + {1} = {2}")
    @MethodSource("sumProvider")
    fun sum(a: Int, b: Int, expected: Int) {
        Truth.assertThat((a + b)).isEqualTo(expected)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun sumProvider(): Stream<Arguments> {
            return Stream.of(
                    Arguments.of(1, 2, 3),
                    Arguments.of(5, 10, 15)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I followed the answers here to adjust a test in Kotlin, and this is how it worked:

```
import org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource

class ParametrizedTestTest {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun hashMapProvider() = mapOf(
            "1" to "Obj1",
            "2" to "Obj2"
        ).entries
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("hashMapProvider")
    fun testMyMapObj(argument: Map.Entry<String, Any>) {
        assertNotNull(argument)
    }
}
```